# Java post json file to elasticsearch with apache http

Tags: json, apache, elasticsearch, http-post

I am able to run curl to upload a file to elasticsearch with `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @other2.json`

The content of the file is

```
{"index":{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":1}}\n
{"title": "Movie1","director": "director1","year":1962}\n
{"index":{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":2}}\n
{"title": "Movie2","director": "director2","year": 1972}\n
{"index":{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":3}}\n
{"title": "Movie3","director": "director3","year": 1972}\n
```

with a new line at the end.

However I am unable to post the same file with apache http client

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JsonResponse http = new JsonResponse();

    System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
    http.sendFile();
}
private void sendFile() throws Exception{
    String fileName = "C:\\other2.json";
    File jsonFile = new File(fileName);


    HttpEntity  entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .addBinaryBody("file", jsonFile,org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON, jsonFile.getName())
        .build();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9200/_bulk");
    post.setEntity(entity);

    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    HttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();

    post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    post.addHeader("Accept","application/json");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    System.out.println("Response: " + response);
}
```

The final output is uninformative

```
Testing 2 - Send Http POST request
Response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Content-Type: application/json; 
charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 152] org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ResponseEntityWrapper@124bec88
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***MultipartEntityBuilder*** adds mime header fields to the request body. This is not valid for the ***bulk api***. 
Also multipart request body has other meta information such as [boundary](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)  in the request body it would result in a bad request

You could use a FileEntity to achieve the same the code Snippet would be something on these line :

```
private void sendFile() throws Exception{
    String fileName = "C://others2.json";
    File jsonFile = new File(fileName);

    HttpEntity  entity = new FileEntity(jsonFile);

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9200/_bulk");
    post.setEntity(entity);

    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    HttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();

    post.addHeader("content-type", "text/plain");
    post.addHeader("Accept","text/plain");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    System.out.println("Response: " + response);
}
```